# Is it possible to call DID number specified in the freepbx inbound routes or freepbx extension from an external mobile phone or landline

Tags: mobile, asterisk

As i am using freepbx 12.0.62 with Asterisk 13.3.2 and i am a newbie to freepbx and asterisk, please suggest that is it possible to call the "DID number" specified in freepbx "Inbound routes" from an external mobile phone or landline phone and routes to an extension destination.

My outbound routing works well when calling from a freepbx extension(1000) to an external number using a destination trunk specified works well.

But for inbound routing when i call from my mobile phone to that inbound route DID, i get "the number you have dialled is not in service" as a response. is there any special setting needed to call?

Also suggest is it possible to call from my mobile phone to my freepbx extension(1000) directly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use custom extensions and/or followme.

Also you can use ringgroup or queue with external number

Message "the number you have dialled is not in service" usually mean you have not configured trunk and/or did number correctly. For more info see sip debug or any other related debug(depend of trunk type)